# How to setup Equinox OSGI framework in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 on Mac OS

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, osgi, equinox

I have an existing Eclipse project using Equinox OSGI framework that has an existing OSGI.launch run configuration that I want to launch using IntelliJ. I'd ideally like IntelliJ to create a run configuration based out of this. But as I did not find any readymade solution, I installed Osmorc plugin and am trying to setup Equinox OSGI framework instance but even though I specified the plugins/eclipse directory, I keep getting an error- 
IDEA cannot find the Equinox framework system bundle in /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/eclipse. Please check your installation.

How do I set it up and can't IntelliJ figure out the directory itself or offer to download and setup the Equinox OSGI framework if missing.

Answer (score 3):

If not too late, I am also trying to create an equinox project on IntelliJ because eclipse always crashes after a new plugin. Here is what I found:

- Download equinox framework from [here](http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/).
- From project settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) -> Languages & Frameworks -> OSGI Framework Instances ->  + (Plus) sign at the right side of the opened frame. -> Choose Equinox
- Reference downloaded folder.

That way you can use equinox.

And you should also add jar files as lib so that you can import them.